# Obter o nome da página atual com JSF 2

Tags: java

Estou usando JSF 2 e preciso obter o nome da página atual, como posso fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é através do `ExternalContext`:

```
((HttpServletRequest) getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getRequestURI()
```